# JAVA using google speech recognition API

Tags: java, api, speech

I'm trying to use google speech recognition API. Here's the code i've written:

http://pastebin.com/zJEhnJ74

It works. I get an answer from the server:

```
{"status":5,"id":"8803471b14a2310dfcf917754e8bd4a7-1","hypotheses":[]}
```

Now the problem is "status:5". Infact, here's status code:

```
status: 0 – correct , status: 4 – missing audio file,  status: 5 – incorrect audio file.
```

My problem is "incorrect audio file". I don't understand if it is a .flac file error (you can download my test .flac file here: http://www21.zippyshare.com/v/61888405/file.html) or how i read the file (in a byte array then convert it into string)

Thanks for help! and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must use `wr.write(data);` instead of `wr.writeBytes(new String(data));`

Google answer:

```
{"status":0,"id":"e0f4ced346ad18bbb81756ed4d639164-1","hypotheses":[{"utterance":"hello how are you","confidence":0.94028234},{"utterance":"hello how r you"},{"utterance":"hello how are u"},{"utterance":"hello how are you in"}]}
```