# facing trouble in using google speech api

Tags: java, speech-recognition, speech, speech-to-text

I am facing trouble when I use my code to interact with google speech api. I have gone through the reference from the following link.
[JAVA using google speech recognition API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16743533/java-using-google-speech-recognition-api)

when I am using his flac file I am getting the text from google api but when I am using my flac file I am getting the following error
Done

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error writing to server
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at test.TestGoogleApiForSpeechRecognition.main(TestGoogleApiForSpeechRecognition.java:42)
```

I have recorded from windows recoder and convert it to flac by using a converter. The coode is given below:

http://pastebin.com/jWnDRrrf

and the flac file is on the following link

http://www8.zippyshare.com/v/91948469/file.html

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I suspect the issue lies in your request property. For instance, for my experimentation, it appears that Google whitelists certain user agents. I would just use [this](https://github.com/The-Shadow/java-speech-api) API to interface with Google.