# Java HttpPost Body Apache 4.3.2

Tags: java, http, http-post

I am trying to make an HttpRequest of type POST using the Apache Java LIB 4.3.2 and I am having a problem.

There is no method to set the body neither a parameter value...

I am trying to set flac binary on the body of the post http request.

Here is my sample code:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;




public class GoogleSpeech {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
            String getURL = "https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?client=chromium&lang=pt-PT&maxresults=10";



            HttpPost get = new HttpPost(getURL);

            get.setHeader("Content-Type", " audio/x-flac; rate=16000;");
            get.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.77 Safari/535.7");



            HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);  
            System.out.println(responseGet);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if I got your question correctly but if you want to set the parameter to an HttpPost instance here is how to do it.

I copied your first part even it I find a bit strage to call "get" an instance of HttpPost :)

```
String getURL = "https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?client=chromium&lang=pt-PT&maxresults=10";
HttpPost get = new HttpPost(getURL);
get.setHeader("Content-Type", " audio/x-flac; rate=16000;");
get.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.77 Safari/535.7");

List<NameValuePair> formparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1", "paramValue1")); // name and value of your param
formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param2", paramValue2));  // name and value of your param
// and so on
// create the encoded form
UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formparams, "UTF-8");
// set it in the post request
get.setEntity(entity);
```

In case you need to upload a binary file sou can use a [MultipartEntity](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntity.html) instead of the UrlEncodedFormEntity. It has an addPart method which can be used for binary blob. I've not tried this line but it should be something similar to:

```
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
entity.addPart("file", new FileBody(new File("your path here")));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and if there are not any param? just the value? I mean: I just want to put a binary flac on the body of the post method.

Comment: I updated the answer, including a reference to MultiPartEntity. Please have a look.

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply, I will test it, will write here soon

Comment: Hey elbuild I did what you suggested and I get this for response:


RESPONSE: HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8, Content-Disposition: attachment, Cache-Control: no-transform, X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff, Pragma: no-cache, Date: Tue, 04 Feb 2014 09:56:17 GMT, Server: S3 v1.0, Content-Length: 0, X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block, X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN]


It was supposed to give me a string of the converted audio, this is what google speech api does, maybe I am not accessing the body of the response? Thanks for your reply

Comment: I'm not familiar with Google Speech API sorry. The 200 code show a success, but you probably need to set a breakpoint somewhere and observe the structure of the response.

Comment: I managed to put it working using another example over here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16743533/java-using-google-speech-recognition-api

Thanks anyway for your effort ;)